# Need to extract entry names from file to populate list or variable

Tags: regex, bash, grep, config

I have this config file with entry names encased in brackets: `[]`. I need to extract each entry name into a list or variable to be used in a `for` loop. Still new and fumbling with some commands. I have a feeling `grep` is my answer but I don't know where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

```
[dropbox]
type = dropbox
scope =  dropbox
token = {"access_token":"my_token"}

[drive2]
type = drive
scope = drive
token = {"access_token":"other_token"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed:

```
sed -rn 's/(^\[)(.*)(\]$)/\2/p' configfile
```

Enable regex with -r. Split each line of the file (configfile) into three sections - start of line,[ then anything (.*) and then ], end of line. Substitute the whole line for just the second section and print.

Comment: Perfect. Does just what I need it to and I think I even understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GNU `grep`:

```
echo "[dropbox]\ntype = dropbox" | grep -Po '\[\K[^\]]*'
# Prints: dropbox
```

Here, `grep` uses the following options:
`-P` : Use Perl regexes.
`-o` : Print the matches only, 1 match/line, not the entire lines.

`\[\K[^\]]*` : literal `[`, escaped, which is followed by the special character `\K` that tells the regex engine to pretend that the match starts at that point, which is followed by any non-`]` character, repeated 0 or more times (`[^\]]*`).

**SEE ALSO:**
[`grep` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)